# Digital signature Inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, digital-signature, authenticode

I would like to know how to sign my setup.exe with Inno setup.
Is it possible to do it for free?
Do I necessarily need a special license for Windows to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two things:

1) A certificate with the code signature flag set (often called Microsoft Authenticode) from a trusted CA (for open souce projects you can get one for free from Certum)

2) The `signtool.exe` tool (part of Windows Kits SDK), see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx